# Bringing workloads from AWS to tencent

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am trying to copy the virtual machine from AWS over to tencent and was wondering if there is an API that will allow me to work with both systems?

Answer (score 1):

No.  You cannot export an image out of AWS.

The exception to this is if you originally created the image outside of AWS, and imported it via the Import/Export tool.

Details [here.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html)